# Using Regular Expression to get String from String

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to get all the amid key values using the regular expression below, but I'm only able to match the first amid key when I test using  https://regex101.com/.

When I use this Java Matcher, I'm getting no results:

```
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

Matcher m = Pattern
             .compile("("amid"): ("\w+\-*+")")
             .matcher(idValue);

while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group());
    System.out.println("------oranges-------" + m.group(1));
}
```

Regular Expression - `("amid"): ("\w+\-*+")`

Where am I going wrong?

```
{"link":"/us_new/en/home","amid":"1__home","title":"Home"},
{"link":"/us_new/en/home/diagnosis-and-treatment",
"amid":"2__diagnosis-and-treatment","title":"Diagnosis and treatment"},
{"link":"/us_new/en/home/diagnosis-and-treatment/diagnosing-hearing-loss",
"amid":"3__diagnosing-hearing-loss","title":"Diagnosing hearing loss"}
```

Comment: If that is a Json String. you could easily parse the json and get the whatever key you want

Comment: `.compile("("amid"): ("\w+\-*+")")` would not compile, and even if you escape quotes as necessary, the problem is your data don't contain the space where you put it into the regex, so the question is off-topic/typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a space in `("amid"): ("\w+\-*+")` after colon. Remove that and your regex will work just fine.

If you want to capture all "amid" tags, use regex `("amid"):("[\w,-]+")`

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\"amid\"):(\"[\\w,-]+\")").matcher("...")
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**Output**

```
"amid":"1__home"
"amid":"2__diagnosis-and-treatment"
"amid":"3__diagnosing-hearing-loss"
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Whats does the , do though?

Comment: \w matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_]). `[\\w,-]` means any word charcter or a `-`.